# Form submission shows error even when radio is checked by default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using [antd](https://ant.design/components/form/). Radio component - https://ant.design/components/radio/.

```
 <Radio.Group buttonStyle="solid" value="Patient">
     <Radio.Button defaultChecked="true" value="Patient">Patient</Radio.Button>
     <Radio.Button value="Doctor">Doctor</Radio.Button>
  </Radio.Group>
```

When I submit the form, it shows the error for required though I set default checked on patient. It works when I select the doctor option and then select patient back.

Comment: Try to use the `defaultValue` property on the `Radio.Group` component instead.

Comment: Also, `defaultChecked` needs to be a boolean, not a string of "true" or "false", i.e. you should have put `defaultChecked={true}`. But Titus' solution is probably better if you can get it to work.

Comment: @Titus i did that too. it still shows the error

Comment: @101arrowz tried it. still get the error

Comment: @Titus it doesn't work in their sandbox example either https://codesandbox.io/s/0pmqu?file=/index.js

Comment: It seems that you have to set the `initialValues` property on the `Form` component, here is an example https://codesandbox.io/s/other-form-controls-ant-design-demo-d0qgv